# inet_ntop function segfault(possibly cast error)

Tags: c, sockets

im trying to understand how to connect internet trough sockets.(but im stuck.cause of segfault.) i dont get why this code gives segfault :S can you help me.

```
int main()
{
    int status;
    WSADATA wsa;
    struct addrinfo hints ,*servinfo;
    struct sockaddr_in *servSock;
    char *ip4;

    /**initialization*/
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2 ,0) ,&wsa);

    memset((void *)&hints ,NULL ,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    ip4 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    /**End of initialization*/

    status = getaddrinfo("www.google.com",DEF_PORT,&hints,&servinfo);
    checkErr("serv info" ,status ,0 ,equal ,gai_strerror);

    servSock = (struct sockaddr_in *)(servinfo->ai_addr);

    status = inet_ntop(AF_INET ,&(servSock->sin_addr) ,ip4,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    checkErr("ntop" ,status ,NULL ,nEqual ,gai_strerror);

    printf("IPv4 : %s",ip4);

    free(ip4);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

code explode at inet_ntop line(idk why,cause im noob ^^ )

Comment: [full version of code](http://pastebin.com/A8Ts4Exv) if you wanna debug it :)

Comment: [image](http://i.imgur.com/8ofQYly.png) i got this watch result when i use `&((struct sockaddr_in *)(servinfo->ai_addr))->sin_addr`

[image](http://i.imgur.com/ZGRDfDd.png) & i got this watch result when i use `&(servSock->sin_addr)`

& what i understand from these results there is something i dont get when i use `servSock = (struct sockaddr_in *)(servinfo->ai_addr);` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
unsigned char ip4buf[4];
memcpy(ip4buf,(struct sockaddr_in *)(servinfo->ai_addr)->sin_addr,4);
...
inet_ntop(AF_INET,(void *) (&ip4buf)ip4,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Comment: inet_ntop(AF_INET ,&(servSock->sin_addr) ,ip4 ,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
i dont get which one is missing ?

`int af --> AF_INET`
`const void *restrict src --> &(servSock->sin_addr)`
`char *restrict dst --> ip4`
`socklen_t size --> INET_ADDRSTRLEN`

isnt it ? @jev

Comment: actually i dont understand that code(im newbie) can u explain it ?

Comment: actually there might be a simpler solution: as you have *servInfo, you should allocate memory for it using malloc

Comment: wasnt getaddrinfo(...) doing that ?

Comment: coulnd't compile your code just now; one idea to double-check is to copy the ip-address in binary format to a buffer first

Comment: thnx for code. it works but I understand what happens in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if &(servSock->sin_addr) is valid.

Comment: actually this code works fine when i try but im trying to get a shorter & easier to understand version.
`status = inet_ntop(AF_INET ,&((struct sockaddr_in *)(servinfo->ai_addr))->sin_addr ,ip4 ,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);`
but when i try to use that code im getting not accessible locations :S

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. When you use windows api's. `gai_strerror(int errno)` makes it unstable and we should use `WSAGetLastError()` function.(gai_strerror changed my servinfo pointer data -after tested my code tons of times i got this result.) & msdn advice to use WSAGetLastError for thread safe usage.

Thnx for any help. & this is my note to this problem.